# How to compare each rows of table

Tags: matlab, struct, comparison-operators, for-in-loop

I want to compare every row of table with every other row of the same table to find row having lowest values.

```
F=table(a,b,c,d)
a=[1 2 1 3, 8 3 1 6]'
b=[3 2 1 3]'
c=[7 9 1 8]'
d=[4 6 1 6]'
```

How can I do it using for loop. Purposely third row is least valued row and it is the final answer. In big table, this is not known in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by the "row having lowest values?" For example, does this mean the sum of the values of that row is lowest? And what if there are multiple rows with the same minimum value?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think your are mistakenly inverting columns and rows here. Anyway, let's make an example with both, using a matrix for the sake of simplicity.

Let's start with rows:

```
A = [
  1 2 1 3;
  8 3 1 6;
  3 2 1 3;
  7 9 1 8;
  4 6 1 6
];

rows_sum = sum(A,2); % row-wise summation
[rows_sum_min,rows_sum_min_idx] = min(rows_sum);
```

The variable `rows_sum_min` will contain the minimum value (`7` in this case) while the variable `rows_sum_min_idx` will contain the row indices that correspond to the minimum value (`1` in this case, the first row).

And now the columns:

```
A = [
  1 2 1 3;
  8 3 1 6;
  3 2 1 3;
  7 9 1 8;
  4 6 1 6
];

cols_sum = sum(A,1); % column-wise summation
[cols_sum_min,cols_sum_min_idx] = min(cols_sum);
```

The variable `cols_sum_min` will contain the minimum value (`3` in this case) while the variable `cols_sum_min_idx` will contain the row indices that correspond to the minimum value (`3` in this case, the third column).

I don't know why you want to to it with a for loop, since the main objective when coding with Matlab is trying to vectorize calculations as much as possible in order to obtain a superior performance. Anyway, if you really want a for loop... here is the example with columns:

```
A = [
  1 2 1 3;
  8 3 1 6;
  3 2 1 3;
  7 9 1 8;
  4 6 1 6
];

[n,m] = size(A);
cols_sum = zeros(1,m);

for i = 1:n
    cols_sum = cols_sum + A(i,:);
end

[cols_sum_min,cols_sum_min_idx] = min(cols_sum);
```

The result will be the same, you just consumed more time and cycles.